# How to create a dynamic multi dimensional array based on given input number such that every array should pushed to its nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I have created an empty string and created a deeply nested array as a string "[[[]]]" then I applied eval function on it to convert it into an array. Is there any better approach than what I have done?

```
    var arrMulti="";
    var n = 3;
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        arrMulti += '['
    }
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        arrMulti += ']'
    }
    arrMulti = eval(arrMulti);
    [[[]]] // console.log(arrMulti);
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why create that array from a string? usually using `eval()` is a bad approach

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make an array of length `n - 1` and call `reduce` on it, constructing a new array around the accumulator on each iteration:

```js
var n = 3;
const arrMulti = new Array(n - 1).fill().reduce(a => [a], []);
console.log(arrMulti);
```

Comment: What do you mean, removing the snippet? Were you encountering [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392370/9515207)?

Comment: yep, i encountered this. Hence i removed the comment again :)